# Magento2 installation - Failed to set PHP CodeSniffer installed_paths Config

Tags: magento2, composer, phpcs

I am trying to install Magento2 using composer.

Getting codesniffer error and tried below steps to overcome the error but unfortunately it's not going away

STEP 1: Tried to install magento2

```
$ composer create-project --repository=https://repo.magento.com/magento/project-community-edition magento2
```

[image]

As you can see, the installation ended up with the error
`Failed to set PHP CodeSniffer installed_paths Config`

STEP 2:
so I tried to install the codesniffer using below command

```
$ composer global require "squizlabs/php_codesniffer=*"
```

successfully installed codesniffer as shown below
[image]

I removed the magento2 directory to start over again

```
$ rm -rf magento2
```

STEP 3: tried to install magento2 again

```
$ composer create-project --repository=https://repo.magento.com/magento/project-community-edition magento2
```

that still ended up with the same error
[image]

I tested the phpcs installation and there seems no issue with it

[image]

Comment: Did you solve this issue anyway?

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu i used below commands,

```
composer require magento/magento-coding-standard:^2.0.0
```

```
vendor/bin/phpcs --config-set installed_paths vendor/magento/magento-coding-standard
```

```
vendor/bin/phpcs --config-set default_standard Magento2
```

Composer loading results from the cache if an issue still exists then append --no-cache in command.